# bitnami MEAN app google search result

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, seo, mean, bitnami

i have my mean app hosted in aws ec2 instance

i have reouted my traffic from port 80 to port 3000

i have routed my godaddy domain to my ec2 instance

when i search for my website "example.com", google search result produces the following result:

```
Bitnami: Open Source. Simplified
example.com/
You are now running Bitnami MEAN 3.2.8-0 in the Cloud. Quick Start Guide ·      
Access RockMongo · Bitnami Wiki · Bitnami Forums. Please check our ...
```

i tried to resolve this using meta tag in my html code but it didnt work.

how to optimise the google search result for my website such that it shows website content instead of BITNAMI?

Answer (score 0):

After you update the the HTMl meta tags google does not reflects the changes right away. You have to wait for google to re index the site or you can send the reindex request using Google Webmaster tools but again there is no known time frame about when Google will re index your website.

http://support.aarcade.net/how-do-i-update-or-change-the-google-search-results-for-my-site/

https://www.google.com/webmasters/#?modal_active=none